# Thought Process for Solving Algebra Equations?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic, algebra

I'm working on a graphing applications that basically graphs equations with on an HTML5 canvas. I had no problem graphing equations that were along the lines of *y=3x^(2)* etc. That was as easy as plugging in a given x value, substituting exponents for native functions and voila!

Ideally however, I'd like to graph equations for circles and other equations that don't necessarily start with *y=...*. This would require actually doing algebra, which, unfortunately is not so easy. My question is: what is the most logical way to solve a problem such as *3x+3y=15*? Let's assume that I'm given an *x* and I'm solving for *y*. How would you go about creating a function that solves it?

Obviously, I could choose to be extremely inefficient and loop through y values until I find one that satisfies the equation, but let's try to avoid that.

I'm not asking for you to write the script for me, I'm just asking for the best/most efficient thought-process to get started.

Currently, this project is being written in Javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (approximate numerical) way is to take your equation re-write it as P(x) = 0 [in your case P(x) = 3(x^2) + 3(y^2) - 15] and then use a numerical technique such as [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find the roots of P(x)

If you want to solve symbolically, then a [Computer Algebra System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) (CAS) is required (non-trivial).

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna come out and say that I used to consider myself decent at math, but you totally lost me. Can you explain where you got "P(x) = 3(x^2) + 3(y^2) - 15" from? Even if it's just some formula or method, just a link to wikipedia will do, just so I can get A more in-depth look at what's going on.

Comment: @WillyG: you mentioned circles, so I assumed you had mistyped 3x+3y=15 ....incorrect assumption it seems! :)

Comment: Oh haha yeah. I wanted to start with a simple example that would be similar to circles. I figure If I can get a basic equation working, then it shouldn't be too hard to expand on that and get more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

`y=3x^(2)` is not linear its quadatric, `3x+3y=15` is in fact linear.

It depends on how complex you want to go, it's not that challenging to write something to rearrange a linear equation like `3x+3y=15` into its standard linear form (`y=5-x`), but it gets harder fast and while there are probably server side libraries for it, i'm not sure about JS.

Answer (score 0):

usually you would express the equation with one variable on one side of the equals sign and the other variable on the other.

If you want to rewrite equations form random user input, you will need some kind of parsing engine.

look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Numerical_Methods/Equation_Solving) for a discussion

Answer (score 0):

The proper name for what you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system